# preg_match with foreach loop

Tags: php, regex

I have text file and it's contain numbers begin with zero.

I want to check that file  line by line that number contain 10 digits and first number to be zero.To that I used this regex `^[0][0-9]{0,9}$`

**Text File Structure:**

```
0123456781
0123456782
0123456783
0123456784
```

**PHP Code :**

```
$array = explode("\n", file_get_contents('numbers.txt'));
```

`$array` like this:
 `Array ( [0] => 0123456781 [1] => 0123456782 [2] => 0123456783 [3] => 0123456784 )`

```
foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
            if (preg_match("/^[0][0-9]{0,9}$/", $value))
                print_r($value);
        }
```

I need display all numbers that are matched with my regex.But it's display only the last number.

Comment: @Uchiha $array content added

Comment: Probably your file has windows-like newlines (\r\n). So your array has such numbers in fact: "0123456781\r", "0123456782\r" etc. Try to explode by "\r\n" or use function `file()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to [`trim`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php) `$value` as it may have spaces or line returns at the end.

```
foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
    if (preg_match("/^0[0-9]{0,9}$/", trim($value)))
        print_r($value);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `preg_grep` with `file` function to get this done without loop:

```
$valids = preg_grep('/^0\d{9}\R?$/', file("data.txt"));

print_r($valids);
```

This will output all the lines from file `data.txt` with matching lines with the regex pattern of `0` and `9 digits`.

**`\R?$` is to take care of input file with DOS file ending.**

Comment: Same result : `Array ( [3] => 0123456784 ) `

Comment: I suspect your file may have \r (DOS line ending). Try my updated answer now.

Comment: Yest `\r` is the problem. +1

Answer (score 2):

Instead of looping through the array taking them individually, you can simply use the [preg-grep()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-grep.php) and the [file()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file.php)

```
$match = preg_grep('/^[0][0-9]{0,9}$/', str_replace(array("\r", "\n"), '', file("numbers.txt")));
```

The `str_replace` will remove all newline and unrequited spaces. Your `$match` will now be an array of all the elements from the `numbers.txt` that matched you pattern.

Comment: I used `if (preg_match("/^0[0-9]{0,9}$/", trim($value)))`

Comment: either works, as long as you understand what it's suppose to do

Answer (score 1):

> I want to check that file line by line that number contain 10 digits and first number to be zero.

Your issue is your regex:

```
"/^[0][0-9]{0,9}$/"
```

needs to be

```
"/^[0][0-9]{9}$/"
```

Next, to trim your array, you can do it like so:

```
$trimmed_array=array_map('trim', $array);
foreach ($trimmed_array as $key => $value) {
    ...
}
```